# How do I set the default value Point(0,0) for center and radius = 1?

Tags: python

Please help me modify this class Circle, (1) setting a default instance.

The circle class uses a Point object as the center. Use center and radius keywords, with the center as the first parameter. Use **repr** and **str** . When assigning point object and radius value to a circle, 
[the output should look like this for assigned values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urZ54.png)

[this is what I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwCUu.png)

Defaults for a circle with no inputs are: center at a default instance of a 
    Point object, and radius of 1.

[This is how the output should look like for default values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jyJdk.png)

[This is what I am getting for defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfxMx.png)

If I am to change the following

```
def __repr__(self):
     return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
                .format(self.center.x,self.center.y,self.radius)
```

to this:

```
def __repr__(self):
      return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius {2})"
                 .format(self.center[0],self.center[1],self.radius)
```

This will create an error, because point object for assigned center Point(2, 3) does not support indexing.

```
 import math
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y  
    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y    
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Point(self.x+other.x,self.y+other.y) 
    def __mul__(self,n):
        return Point(self.x*n,self.y*n) 
    def __rmul__(self,n):
        return Point(n*self.x,n*self.y) 
    @classmethod
    def from_tuple (cls, self=(0,0)):
        return cls(*self)   
    def loc_from_tuple(self,t=(0,0)):
        self.x=t[0]
        self.y=t[1] 
    def __str__(self):
        return "Point at ({0}, {1})".format(self.x,self.y)  
    def __repr__(self):
        return"Point(x={0}, y={1})".format(self.x,self.y)   
    @property
    def magnitude(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2+self.y**2)   
    def distance (self, other):
        return math.sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2)       
    def shift(p1, p2):
        mx = p1.x+p2.x
        my = p1.y+p2.y
        return Point(mx,my) 
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, center=(0,0), radius=1):
        Point.__init__(self,center)
        self.center=center
        self.radius=radius
    def __str__(self):
        return "Circle with center at ({0}, {1}) and radius {2}"
        .format(self.center.x, self.center.y, self.radius)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
        .format(self.center.x,self.center.y,self.radius)
    def __add__(self,other):
        return Circle(
        Point(self.center.x+other.center.x,
        self.center.y+other.center.y),
        self.radius+other.radius)
    @classmethod
    def from_tuple(cls, center,radius):
        return cls(center, radius)
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, radius):
        if radius<0:
            raise ValueError('The radius cannot be negative')
        self._radius=radius
    @property
    def diameter(self):
        return self._radius*2
    @diameter.setter
    def diameter(self, diameter):
        if diameter<0:
            raise ValueError('The radius cannot be negative')
        self._radius = diameter/2
    @property
    def area(self):
        return math.pi*self.radius**2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Center is a tuple, so it does not have an attribute `x`. Here you define center:

```
class Circle(Point):
    def __init__(self, center=(0,0), radius=1):
        Point.__init__(self,center)
        self.center=center
```

And here you call `center.x`

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
    .format(self.center.x,self.center.y,self.radius)
```

A quick workaround would be to change `__repr__` to something like:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
    .format(self.center[0],self.center[1],self.radius)
```

That way you will be indexing the tuple. Another approach will be to make center a dictionary like `center = {'x':0, 'y'0}`. Then `__repr__` will work as is although you will have to go through the rest of your program to ensure consistency.

Comment: making this change will conflict with an assigned center, which is a Point object that does not support indexing. Let's say if center is Point(2,3), __repr__ will be unable to format self.center[0] or self.center[1].

Comment: I see, change `Point.__init__(self,center)` to `center = Point(*center)` that way, center will be a point, right now it is just a tuple

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you everything you need to know:
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'x'

The offending line is this one:

```
return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
.format(self.center.x,self.center.y,self.radius)
```

The object `center` is a tuple, meaning its variables are accessed with indices, not attribute names. Try instead:

```
return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
.format(self.center[0],self.center[1],self.radius)
```

What would be even better is to actually make use of the inheritance `Circle` has from `Point` and access `x` and `y` directly - there is no reason to keep the `center` as an instance variable if you have all you need already there:

```
return "Circle(center=Point({0}, {1}), radius={2})"
.format(self.x,self.y,self.radius)
```